# Is it possible to programmatically set the start background photo in WP8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I've explored to find out API but nothing found. If anybody knows please help me to do that.

Comment: the choice of start background photo is up to the user, the system should not provide such an API. Microsoft has learned this from the early versions of Windows when a program could add itself to user's list of "my favorite programs".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such an API exists.

There is a vote on [uservoice.com](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1720049-provide-a-wallpaper-api-to-enable-in-app-setting-o) for this, but the response is clear, even though it is possible to set the lock screen wallpaper starting from WP8.0,

> ...the story has not changed for the start screen background.

It was 2 years ago, i am not sure if this has changed in WP8.1.